# Desplazamiento de un array en Java

Tags: java, array

Tengo un array con enteros

```
int[] intColorArray = new int[3];
```

Me gustaría obtener un valor diferente secuencialmente del array pero si se llega al final que vuelve a obtener des de el inicio, es decir

`0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2...`

Habia pensado en hacer un desplazamiento lateral a la izquierda y el valor volverlo a poner al final y así solo obtener la posición `0` me devolveria el color secuencialmente.

No encuentro en java como hacer un shift izquierda en un array

Comment: No tengo muy claro a que te refieres, porque lo que yo entiendo de tu pregunta se soluciona con `valor = intColorArray[i % intColorArray.length]`

Comment: @SJuan76 pues si es eso lo que queria, si quieres agregar una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea seria si el indice buscado es mayor al tam del arreglo, hacer la diferencia:`n=n-array.length;` hasta que ya no sea mayor.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int [] a={1,2,3,4};
        secuenceGetID(a,6);
    }

    public static int secuenceGetID(int[] array, int n){

        while(n>=array.length){
            n=n-array.length;

        }
        System.out.println(array[n]);
        return array[n];

    }
}
```

ahora presento otra solucion, **por congruencia de numeros**, es decir:

```
26 es congruente a 11 con modulo 5
26%5==1    y      11%5==1
```

segun esta analogia, solamente bastaria con: `n=n%array.length`;

```
ejemplo:  * n=5 es el indice a buscar
          * mi array es {1,2,3,4}, con tam de 3
          entonces 5%3=2 el resultado sera 3
```

**el codigo seria:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int [] a={1,2,3,4};
        secuenceGetID(a,6);
    }

    public static int secuenceGetID(int[] array, int n){

            n=n%array.length;

        System.out.println(array[n]);
        return array[n];

    }
}
```